# substring varchar get first globalid

Tags: sql, substring

I have varchar string and need return first globalid value - 8679926300927194610
My string:

```
 declare @erservice varchar(max) = 'globalid=8679926300927194610,ou=services,globalid=00000000000000000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the following. Assuming that the string always starts globalid=, and there is a comma after the number.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@erservice,10,CHARINDEX(',',@erservice)-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring and charindex, given that the string always starts with globalid=n

For easier readability I will replace the string with @yText
`(@yText = 'globalid=8679926300927194610,ou=services,globalid=00000000000000000000')`

```
DECLARE @erservice varchar(max) = substring(@yText, 10, CHARINDEX(',',@yText)-10)
```

Substring will give you the offset to start extracting from, while Charindex will show the end of the numbers by searching for the place of the comma.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx